# View output that goes from list to three-column grid?

Tags: views, theming

I'm working on a news site, which has a front page generated via Views.

Originally I was told it was just a straight list of stories, so I used the unformatted list display type, using on of the fields ("section") to group rows. Now, however, I'm being told it'd be nice to have the first ten stories display as an unformatted list, then have the next ten display in some sort of three-column configuration (similar to the "grid" display type).

Any idea how I'd do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking to create two views. And add them one above the other in a panel. The first view has 10 items in an unformatted list then the next ten would have a grid display of the same content but with an offset of 10.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but then I'd have to enable Panels again, which uses so much memory...

Comment: panels is the easy way, you could opt to load the views from the template file or from a node's content (php filter) with straight code.